# What could cause a Labwindows/CVI C program to hate the number 2573?

Tags: c, memory, labwindows, cvi

Using Windows

So I'm reading from a binary file a list of unsigned int data values.   The file contains a number of datasets listed sequentially.  Here's the function to read a single dataset from a char* pointing to the start of it:

```
function read_dataset(char* stream, t_dataset *dataset){

    //...some init, including setting dataset->size;

    for(i=0;i<dataset->size;i++){
        dataset->samples[i] = *((unsigned int *) stream);
        stream += sizeof(unsigned int);
    }
    //...
}
```

Where read_dataset in such a context as this:

```
//...
char buff[10000];
t_dataset* dataset = malloc( sizeof( *dataset) );
unsigned long offset = 0;

for(i=0;i<number_of_datasets; i++){

    fseek(fd_in, offset, SEEK_SET);

    if( (n = fread(buff, sizeof(char), sizeof(*dataset), fd_in)) != sizeof(*dataset) ){
        break;
    }

    read_dataset(buff, *dataset);

    // Do something with dataset here.  It's screwed up before this, I checked.


    offset += profileSize;
}
//...
```

Everything goes swimmingly until my loop reads the number 2573. All of a sudden it starts spitting out random and huge numbers.

For example, what should be

```
...
1831
2229
2406
2637
2609
2573
2523
2247
...
```

becomes

```
...
1831
2229
2406
2637
2609
0xDB00000A
0xC7000009
0xB2000008
...
```

If you think those hex numbers look suspicious, you're right.  Turns out the hex values for the values that were changed are really familiar:

```
2573 -> 0xA0D
2523 -> 0x9DB
2247 -> 0x8C7
```

So apparently this number 2573 causes my stream pointer to gain a byte.  This remains until the next dataset is loaded and parsed, and god forbid it contain a number 2573.  I have checked a number of spots where this happens, and each one I've checked began on 2573.

I admit I'm not so talented in the world of C.  What could cause this is completely and entirely opaque to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't specify how you obtained the bytes in memory (pointed to by stream), nor what platform you're running on, but I wouldn't be surprised to find your on Windows, and you used the C stdio library call `fopen(filename "r");` Try using `fopen(filename, "rb");`. On Windows (and MS-DOS), fopen() translates MS-DOS line endings "\r\n" (hex 0x0D 0x0A) in the file to Unix style "\n", unless you append "b" to the file mode to indicate binary.

Comment: Thank you good sir, I understand the error of my ways (and yeah, I forgot the "b").

Comment: I used to occaisonally forget the "b", and recognized the symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of irrelevant points.

sizeof(*dataset) doesn't do what you think it does.

There is no need to use seek on every read

I don't understand how you are calling a function that only takes one parameter but you are giving it two (or at least I don't understand why your compiler doesn't object)

Comment: I may be mouthfooting, but I did leave some things out of my code.  Each dataset contains a small header which indicates the number of samples, which isn't consistent between files.  Therefore, t_dataset is the size of the biggest dataset I expect to encounter.  That's probably wrong, but in my defense I didn't write that.

So, fseek compensates for the overshoot.